# How to workaround switch noise

Tags: audio, amplifier, noise

I lately built a 10W amplifier using a TDA2003. I used this circuit (though I removed R4 since I didn't have it, C4 is 50n (two 100n's in series) and R1 is 50Ohm (two 100Ohm's parallel)):

[image]

Everything worked fine and there was no noise as far as I could hear.

Now, I wanted to be able to switch between two inputs, like this:

[image]

This works, but I get a lot of noise now. All wires are shielded, so I concluded the noise arises in the switch and is amplified after that. Is this correct or am I jumping to conclusions?

How can I decrease the noise? I do not want to switch later,  after the amplification, that would produce too much heat and consume too much energy since I'd have to amplify two signals of which I'd only use one.

Comment: Where did you get 50 ohm resistor and 50 farad capacitor?

Comment: Combined from two 100Ohm resistors and two 100n capacitors (not 50 _farad_, 50 _nanofarad_) (I edited my question to add this information)

Comment: @AndrejaKo - 50 ohm resistors are available from [the shop](http://uk.farnell.com/vishay-dale/crcw060350r0fkea/resistor-thick-film-50r-100mw-1/dp/2112878) just like other values. I don't see a 50F capacitor anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the n. Anyway, what type of switch are you exactly using? How "clean" is the environment electrically? Do you have any obvious noise sources that could couple into the switch?  Do you have noise with no input to the amplifier? Do you have noise with input?

Comment: [The switch](http://www.conrad.nl/medias/global/ce/7000_7999/7000/7000/7003/700337_LB_00_FB.EPS_1000.jpg) is a 'normal' one, max resistance when connecting 10mOhm. I don't know what you mean with "clean", obvious sources, etc. so some general info: the switch and the amplifier are in the same case which is grounded. The switch is grounded too. The transformer is in the same case but didn't produce noise without the switch so can't be the problem. The supply voltage is clean. As I said, there wasn't any problem before adding the switch. If you need any other information, please do not hesitate!

Comment: For one thing, you don't need to switch the ground leads on the input connectors; just tie them all together. Can you describe the noise? Is it just a click when switching, random crackling and/or hiss, or hum?

Comment: It is a constant hiss (I think), it's like the sound of the sea you hear in those shells. I added - temporarily - a little volume control potmeter before the amplifier, and the noise increases/decreases while changing the potmeter's value, which shows the noise indeed is on the input. I'm going to link the ground leads together now!

Comment: @DaveTweed I linked the grounds and moved the inputs from each other. Everything's working fine again. What should I do? This question seems a bit useless to me now, since the solution doesn't solve the problem I assumed in the question...

Comment: @Camil Staps I thing that the best idea would be to actually figure out what was happening. Just "link grounds together" doesn't explain the underlying problem, although it does provide hints. As for the "clean" part, I meant if there are any sources of electrical noise such as switch-mode power supplies, inverters, powerful CCFLs or similar that could emit electrical fields which could  be picked up by switch assembly.

Comment: Right, so the hint would be that the inactive signal becomes noise because the ground isn't grounded? For the rest, I do have a clean environment, yes, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to debug and try and solve this I'd suggest the following (requires oscilloscope):

1)Use an oscilloscope with FFT capability on the output. Then you can tell what is the spectrum of the interference. In fact in Audio system testing, this is done with automated equipment to ensure a high SNR. If the noise is rather narrow, then it's likely something is oscillating and that's easier to fix than if it is wideband.

2) Connect an oscilloscope to VCC and take a look. Do you see anything out of the ordinary like waves riding on it? If you do, an LDO or regulator can act as a low pass filter and filter a lot of noise out of it. Might be a good idea to use a clean supply as well.

Comment: I guess that would have solved the issue as well, so I accepted it. Thanks!